# How to install CyanogenMod using downloaded i777.zip file for Samsung Galaxy i777 (~Galaxy S2)?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to install CyanogenMod for my Samsung Galaxy i777 (~ Galaxy S2).
1) I've installed CyanogenMod Installer apk
2) The app redirected me to http://get.cm
3) I found my i777 link which redirected me to https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=i777
3) There i was proposed to download https://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/134244/cm-12.1-20151111-NIGHTLY-i777.zip
4) This zip contains the files below.

Also I've found and downloaded Windows Installer but it also redirected to donwload this zip

Question: how to install CyanogenMod in this case?

Thank you very much!

i777.zip:
install\,
META-INF\,
system\,
boot.img,
file_contexts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your device is already rooted. so all you have to do is to install a custom recovery to install any custom ROMs including CyanogenMod.

1. Download CWM custom recovery for you device (or TWRP) here is a link http://galaxys2root.com/cwmtwrp-recovery/ and make sure you backed up your apps and you ready as the custom recovery will install a new kernel that will make your current software unbootable.
2. Download Odin for flashing on Samsung devices from here.http://odindownload.com/ and then open it and connect your Mobile
3. Download the custom ROM zip file or if you already have yours.
   **NOTE: PLEASE ONLY INSTALL ROMS INTENDED FOR YOUR VERSION OF Galaxy S2! Otherwise you WILL BRICK YOUR PHONE and I will not be responsible!**
4. Put your zip file on your phone internal storage and then enter bootloader mode by turning off then pressing Volume Down + Power + Home button (check if it's different for S2).
5. Press PDA button and select your CWM file and check the Auto Boot checkbox and make sure Re-Partition is unchecked then hit start.
6. You phone now will boot into recovery. Wipe cache and delvik(Wiping everything will give you a clean install) and select install zip and navigate using Volume buttons to your **ZIP** file and press power button to select. Then choose flash (YES among several NOs). Then wait to finish flashing.
7. Go back and select system reboot and then you'll have your **CyanogenMod ROM** booting.

Comment: Omar, thank you very much! Especially your "Wiping everything will give you a clean install" really helped